# Custom CSS radio button labels

Tags: html, css, elementor

how can i make all blocks the same and have 10px margin between them?
The radio button has been changed to a radio label. The problem is that the sizes are different, so the length of the words is different. How can it be done in one size?

[image: I would like to get this result]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72410729/edit) to include the HTML and CSS you are starting with.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: flex may be what you need but difficult to say without seeing your code. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help with doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```css
#radios {
  position: relative;
  background-color: tomato;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 363px;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
#bckgrnd,
.labels {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-right: -3px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
#bckgrnd {
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
#rad1:checked ~ #bckgrnd {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#rad2:checked ~ #bckgrnd {
  transform: translateX(120px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#rad3:checked ~ #bckgrnd {
  transform: translateX(241px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="radios">
  <input id="rad1" type="radio" name="radioBtn" checked>
  <label class="labels" for="rad1">First Option</label>
  <input id="rad2" type="radio" name="radioBtn">
  <label class="labels" for="rad2">Second Option</label>
  <input id="rad3" type="radio" name="radioBtn">
  <label class="labels" for="rad3">Third Option</label>
  <div id="bckgrnd"></div>
</div>
```